# Cucumber: scenario for User is not signed up is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I ran cucumber for the [devise-rspec-cucumber project](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber) but the following scenario is failing:

```
Scenario: User is not signed up
  Given I do not exist as a user
  When I sign in with valid credentials
  Then I see an invalid login message
    And I should be signed out
```

undefined method `flatten' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

1 scenario (1 failed)

4 steps (4 passed)

I tried removing every step except the first one and it is still failing:

```
Given /^I do not exist as a user$/ do
  create_visitor
  delete_user
end
```

where

```
def create_visitor
  @visitor ||= { :name => "Testy McUserton", :email => "example@example.com",
    :password => "changeme", :password_confirmation => "changeme" }
end

def delete_user
  @user ||= User.where(:email => @visitor[:email]).first
  @user.destroy unless @user.nil?
end
```

But if I replace create_visitor with create_user, it will pass.

```
def create_user
  create_visitor
  delete_user
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, @visitor)
end
```

I am confused what's going on. It seems to me that the step definition is expecting some things that I am not providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error message before. I was sure that there's nothing wrong with my steps. Therefore I tried to upgrade the database_cleaner gem to the latest (1.0.1) since the error was caused by database_cleaner. And it did solve the problem. I would suggest you try this if your database_cleaner gem version is not 1.0.1. Just do

$ bundle update database_cleaner

Answer (score 0):

The problem exist here:

```
  create_visitor
  delete_user
```

In the first step you created a **visitor**, but not an **user**. Then in second step you try to delete an user who does not exist. That's why the test failed.

I suggest you to review the logic and create correct steps.

Comment: @user2191332, I can't make more judgements due to lack of error info. But apparently the logic in `delete_user` is not solid,  `@user` doesn't exist. And `User.where(:email => @visitor[:email]).first` will also throw exception.

Comment: So I guess @user.nil? is causing the error. But if I remove delete_user, and only running the statement Given /^I do not exist as a user$/, the same error occurs and I have no idea why. Also, cucumber is not telling me where the error is occurring. Is there a way to turn that on?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where `flatten` happens. It seems there is no such logic in the code you've shown. To show more errors, you can run cucumber with parameter `-b`, which will show backtrace details.

Comment: If I leave the step definition completely blank, should the scenario be passing? Because the same error shows up. What is the reason for a scenario failing if all the steps are passing?

Comment: Good point! Actually I  think this line is totally useless `Given I do not exist as a user`. If you are not an user, just visit that page, that's all, there is nothing to do!

Comment: Or the line is useful, but there is no need to do anything.